# Get properties of runtime created list item in Unity

Tags: list, unity-game-engine, properties

I have a scroll list with runtime generated items. Each item has some properties and has 3 buttons Like, Comment and Delete.
Now I want to catch the onClick event of the Like button of an item, so how can I get the property of the item from the onClick()?

```
List
   Item1
       Name(Text)
       ID(string)
       Logo(Image)
       Like(Button)
       Comment(Button)
       Delete(Button)
   Item2
   Item3
   Item4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I already created the prefab for the list item, along with its properties so I figured out a way to access its grandparent's properties by using this code

```
GameObject parent = this.transform.parent.transform.parent.gameObject;
PostItem item = parent.GetComponent<PostItem>();
postID = item.PostID;
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a prefab of the Item.
2. Create a script and attach it to the prefab
3. In the script create a `public` property of type `Button`
4. In the inspector drag the `Like` button to the script.

After you have done that you'll be able to access the button and work with it.

I did something similar and came up with a weird issue that I fixed following this thread [4.6 UI How to apply OnClick handler for button generated at runtime (script)](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/791573/46-ui-how-to-apply-onclick-handler-for-button-gene.html)

Hope it helps you.